# Need help connecting to NAS externally-port forwarding and DDNS newbie

Tags: networking, router, dyndns

I just picked up a synology NAS, and I'm loving it for internal use, but I want to be able to access the NAS externally-both from my iPhone (3G) and from the net.

I have a Linksys WRT54G-TM router.

My first question is whether I have set up the dyndns correctly.

On my computer that is on my network, if I put in mydomain.dyndns.org, I am taken to a password popup and when I enter my router login and password, my router admin page opens up.

On the same computer, I get the same results if I use my external IP address, and if I use my internal IP 192.168.0.1

So that is all as expected.

However, when I go to my iphone and turn off wifi, and try to connect with 3g to the external IP or the dnydns domain, I just get an error "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding".

What's up?

Comment: should be on superuser.com

Comment: Why?  To the right of the question edit screen: "Is your question about servers, networking, or desktop infrastructure?" Yes, yes, and yes.  This question is the first step in getting my network to connect to my server.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: from the [SF FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq): "Server Fault is for system administrators and desktop support professionals" - Those lines can get blurred a bit, but your question is most definitely a *home* configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:
To point to a specific port, you need to have that in the address bar.

mydomain.dyndns.org will not work.

mydomain.dyndns.org:5000   (pointing to port 5000) will work.